# passing asp.net session data to angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

We are in the process of migrating a part of the ASP/ASP.net application to AngularJS.  I need to be able to get data (ex. UserTypeId, security info, etc) from the ASP.net Session to the AngujarJS pages since that data is used as keys to access other data via web service.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to pass this data along?

One thought is to make an ASPX page with a series of hidden fields that is also has the Angular tag and access to Angular Controllers.  When the page controller came up it could read the values from the hidden fields and pass the values along to a service that all the controllers could access. But this leave me in some weird ASP page that is really an angular page.

Jerry

Comment: I guess the best approach for this is to make a $http call from your AngularJS Service or Ctrler to your 'Code Behind' layer to retrieve this data.

Comment: Always seems best to create RESTful services and simply communicate with them using JSON.  If your ASP.net app has an endpoint like http://www.example.com/loggedInUser that responds to a GET with a JSON encoded result then consuming that from Angular will be trivial

Comment: I figured this out.    The Angular piece is just part of the pipeline.  So it is started by asp page.  That page can pass the Angular page the  information via Post.

Comment: can you please show your code, f.x i have default.aspx and if i write script to assigned session variable, how you access in your controller. or are you calling other page. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am researching same issue, one of the possible solutions could be

1. Pass data encoded as query string
2. Save data in cookie from ASP.NET and read from cookie in Angular JS

Thoughts?